# How to Include ENVIRONMENT variables in the AWSCLI command that uses JSON input

Tags: aws-cli

I should be able to pass Environment Variables as Input for my AWSCLI command's JSON Input. Im however, not able to give that information as literally put the data defined under double quotes.

```sh
export IMAGEID=ami-xxxxx
export InstanceType=t2x.large

aws ec2 create-launch-template --launch-template-name TemplateForWebServer --version-description WebVersion1 --launch-template-data '{"NetworkInterfaces":[{"AssociatePublicIpAddress":true,"DeviceIndex":0,"Ipv6AddressCount":1}],"ImageId":"$IMAGEID","InstanceType":"$InstanceType","TagSpecifications":[{"ResourceType":"instance"}]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your single-quotes (`'`) are deactivating variable substitution.

For example:

```
$ export foo="abc"

$ echo $foo
abc

$ echo '{"key":"$foo"}'
{"key":"$foo"}

$ echo {"key":"$foo"}
{key:abc}

$ echo {\"key\":\"$foo\"}
{"key":"abc"}
```